# Django ORM multiple distinct and order by

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I work on a simple chat app. I need to query db for an user to get last message of user conversation to other users. Same as main page of whatsapp and telegram.

**Model:**

```
class CHAT(models.Model):
    sender_uid = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True)
    receiver_uid = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True)
    message = models.TextField(verbose_name='Message Text')
    created = models.IntegerField(default=created_time_epoch)
```

I tried this query:

```
message_list = self.model.objects.filter(Q(sender_uid=user_uid)|Q(receiver_uid=user_uid)).order_by('receiver_uid', 'sender_uid', '-created').distinct('receiver_uid', 'sender_uid')
```

**Output:**

```
<QuerySet [<CHAT: ted@ted.com Message: hello 4 To: saeed@saeed.com>, <CHAT: marshal@marshal.com Message: hello6 To: saeed@saeed.com>, <CHAT: saeed@saeed.com Message: hello 5 To: ted@ted.com>]>
```

My problem is I get two last message from each conversation (if both user send message to each other), In one of them user is sender and in other one user is receiver.

For now I handle it with below code:

```
message_send_list = list(self.model.objects.filter(sender_uid=user_uid).order_by('receiver_uid', '-created').distinct('receiver_uid'))
message_receive_list = list(self.model.objects.filter(receiver_uid=user_uid).order_by('sender_uid', '-created').distinct('sender_uid'))
temp_list = []
for s_message in message_send_list:
    r_message = next((item for item in message_receive_list if item.sender_uid == s_message.receiver_uid), None)
    if r_message is not None:
        message_receive_list.pop(message_receive_list.index(r_message))
        if s_message.created > r_message.created:
            temp_list.append(s_message)
        else:
             temp_list.append(r_message)
    else:
        temp_list.append(s_message)
temp_list.extend(message_receive_list)
```

**Output:**

```
[<CHAT: saeed@saeed.com Message: hello 5 To: ted@ted.com>, <CHAT: marshal@marshal.com Message: hello6 To: saeed@saeed.com>]
```

My question is how can I get this result in one query? Problem is user can be sender and receiver of message and I can't distinguish which one is last message of conversation. How to filter or distinct on that?

Comment: So you want *one* message, the last one that is send or received? I find it a bit strange that you here use two messages.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes, I want last message of every conversation of user, send or received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the description of the problem, you make it a bit too complex. You can obtain the *other person* with a [conditional expression [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/). So by first making a "reduction" where we take the other person, we can then use a uniqueness filter for that:

```
from django.db.models import Case, F, When

last_messages = self.model.objects.filter(
    Q(sender_uid=user_uid) | Q(receiver_uid=user_uid)
).annotate(
    other=Case(
        When(sender_uid=user_uid, then=F('receiver_uid')),
        default=F('sender_uid'),
        output_field=CharField()
    )
).order_by('other', '-created').distinct('other')
```

Furthermor all `Chat` objects will have an extra attribute: `other` that thus contains the non-`user_uid` side.

Comment: Thank you, I tried it but get this error: *** django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT ON (other) "chat__chat"."id",...

Comment: @Saeed: what if you add `'other'` in the `order_by` function (as first parameter).

Comment: then order will by user_uid in other not created

Comment: @Saeed: well we can fetch the latest messages per user, and then manually sort the *latest* messages. But this will have not much impact anyway, since we already fetch these messages from the database, so this will at most convert an *O(n)* to an *O(n log n)* solution. By using an `other` we can reduce the number of elements by a factor 2, and sorting is rather straightforward with `sorted(my_qs, key=lambda x: x.created, reversed=True)`.

Comment: Thank you, Now I think '-created' in order_by is redundant

Comment: @Saeed: no it is not, since if you do not specify that order, it will just pick *any* message. By ordering it, we force the database to pick the last message with that person.